# How to mass convert all spaces to tabs in Xilinx Vivado

Tags: xilinx, vivado

How do you convert an entire HDL file from spaces to tabs in Xilinx Vivado?

I've given my own answer below but won't vote on it one way or the other.

Is there a better way that anyone knows?

Comment: As I also prefer tab-characters for indentation, I don't recommend tabs for alignment (e.g. for assignment signs or colons).

Answer (score 1):

To convert an entire HDL module in Vivado from spaces to tabs:

1. Set the environment to use the tab character when the tab key is struck (in lieu of four spaces).
2. Indent the entire HDL file in the text editor by highlighting everything and pressing the Tab key.
3. De-indent the entire HDL file by highlighting everything and pressing Shift-Tab.

To change to Tab mode in the first place, select the Tools->Settings menu.
On the left side of the settings window that shows up, under Tool Settings, click the carrot next to the Text Editor to reveal the options. Then click on the Tabs label to reveal the Tab options panel.
Check the box that says "Use Tabs Character".

Comment: As this is the correct procedure, Vivado is very slow on large files. I suggest to use a smarter editor like Notepad++ for such big edits. The indent, deindent procedure is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check Notepad++ out. -DF